# Загрузить картинку и вывести её часть на экран

Tags: массивы, изображения, c++

Здравствуйте!
Пишу программу, которая работает с изображениями.
Задача: использовать как можно меньше озу, а работать программа должна как можно быстрее. Упор сделаю на быстрее т.к. все операции проводятся 40 раз в секунду.
В чем проблема, нужно *загрузить* большую картинку и выводить ее часть на экран.
проблема в том, что именно **загрузить** и после этого **выводить**.

Чтобы загрузить, нужно создать большой динамический массив и в него скопировать картинку, а потом из массива по индексу только и остается выводить нужную область картинки. Расходуется много памяти.

Или другой вариант: Открыть файл картинки на чтение, файлсиком сосчитать из определенной области, сколько нужно в массив, а из массива вывести на экран. Памяти расходуется гораздо меньше, но операций выполняется, как я понимаю, на много больше. Недостаток-нагрузка на процессор.

Во втором случае программа начинает жутко тормозить. Что можете посоветовать? Спасибо.

Comment: в каком формате картинка? не все можно просто так взять и загрузить с произвольного места.

А в скорость жесткого диска не упираетесь?

Comment: картинка не важно какая, считаем что она массив цветов на диске, типа bmp. Скорость диска,... программа будет работать на коммуникаторе...

Comment: Если речь идет о загрузке содержимого файла в память "один в один", то попробуйте просто mmap-нуть файл.

Comment: какая картинка - это не важно. Важен формат. Если это png, то просто так нельзя загрузить.

Может проще подготовить картинки сразу и тогда подгружать будет проще?

Что за задача решается?  Не делаете ли случайно свои "карты"?

Comment: ну да, картинка на самом деле подготовлена.) Да, делаю карты)

Comment: про mmap, в данном случае у меня не Unix

Comment: @Alerr, не \*nix - это зря. Но, в данном случае - неважно, т.к. в винде есть какой-то эквивалент.

Вообще, см., например, [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Так как выяснилось, что автор делает карты, то здесь есть готовое решение, которое работает достаточно быстро.

Карту разделяют на квадраты известного размера. Если нужно масштабирование, то подготавливают кратные размеры (то есть, для каждого квадрата есть 4 квадрата поменьше).

Теперь, когда нужно отобразить карту, просто рассчитывается для текущего поля, какие квадраты нужно подгрузить и их отображают. Когда пользователь продвигается в сторону, нужно просто подгрузить ещё несколько квадратов. Если квадратам дать номера в виде "размер-xкоордината-yкоордината.расширение" (например `1-2-3.jpg`), то их будет очень легко найти.

Плюсы:

- При правильном выборе квадратов, в памяти храниться не более чем двукратный размер картинки.
- При пролистывании картинки быстро подгружаются. Если пользователь сильно резко пролиснул, то можно даже пропустить подгрузку, отобразив пустышку.
- Для некоторых областей можно использовать одну и ту же картинку (к примеру, отображая море), для некоторых областей можно использовать картинки пониженного качества (пустырь), что позитивно сказывается на размере)
- Так делают почти все известные "карты" - гугл, яндекс, 2гис, бинг.
- Если выбрать правильный размер (например 128х128), то можно использовать картинки как текстуры для OpenGL движка, что может хорошо ускорить работу.

Минусы:

- Картинки нужно подготавливать отдельно.
- Стыки между картинками иногда могут быть сильно заметны.
- При наличии большого кол-ва файлов в одной папке все может начать подтормаживать, решается разбрасыванием картинок по папкам либо созданием своего формата.\
- Сложнее крутить. Придется рассчитывать правильные преобразования.